# How to replace value of array in javascript with another value of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, str-replace, array-replace

I'm trying to replace values from an array which are present in a string with another array. What is the best way to do this in Javascript?
here is my code :

```
var string = "I've to but the Item1 along with Item2 and Item3. From the Item4."
var array1 = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']
var array2 = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4']
```

and output should be like this

```
var replaced = "I've to but the Product1 along with Product2 and Product3. From the Product4."
```

every value in both arrays is completely different from each other.

Comment: May you make your example a [mcve]?

Comment: what are the values of those variables, `Item1` ... `Item4` and `Product1` ... `Product4`

Comment: @JaromandaX links

Comment: links, right so like `http://example.com`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the string using [String.prototype.replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
const input = "I've to but the Item1 along with Item2 and Item3. From the Item4.";
const original = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4'];
const target = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4'];

let result = input;
original.forEach((item, index) => {
  result = result.replaceAll(item, target[index]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that replaceAll is not a function

Comment: On which browser are you chking?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have been helpful.

```js
var array1 = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4'];
var array2 = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3', 'Product4'];
var string = "I've to but the Item1 along with Item2 and Item3. From the Item4.";

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    var string = string.replace(array1[i], array2[i]);
}

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literal for e.g.

```
var array1 = [Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4];
var array2 = [Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4]
var string = `I've to but the ${array1[0]} along with ${array1[1]} and ${array1[2]}. From the 
${array1[3]}.`
var replaced = `I've to but the ${array2[0]} along with ${array2[1]} and ${array2[2]}. 
From the ${array2[3]}.`
```

Comment: actually, I'm taking that string as input from the user so can't use template literal